# How can i generate Data from .gdf files using Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python

I'm preparing my dataset to be preprocessed before training with CNN model but i couldn't generate data from this type of file which contain several signals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using the gdflib library. It'll allow you to process your .gdf files by organizing your data into nodes for further processing.

It would also help if you could please provide a minimal reproducible example of what you have tried.